# Align a <ul> inside a <li> in one column next to the li

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a `<ul>` inside a `<li>` and i want to align the text like this (see screen shot).

How can i do that ?

[image]

```html
<ul>
  <li>TEXT 1</li>
  <li>
    <span>TEXT 2</span>
    <ul>
      <li>TEXT A</li>
      <li>TEXT B</li>
      <li>TEXT C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>TEXT 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use `display: flex`

```css
.flexcontainer {display: flex}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>TEXT 1</li>
  <li class="flexcontainer">
    <span>TEXT 2</span>
    <ul>
      <li>TEXT A</li>
      <li>TEXT B</li>
      <li>TEXT C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>TEXT 3</li>
</ul>
```